# Getting string value from SQL function inside a CLR

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

Attempted (non-working) solution included below.
I have an sql function called get_parameter which looks in a table for a given string and returns the associated string:

```
declare @str varchar(20);
set @str = dbo.get_parameter('filecount')
print @str
```

It works!  I run this and it prints out exactly what it should print.  In this case, the parameter is the string '44'.

Now I want to run a C# CLR.  But I want the CLR to be able to look up the parameter that it needs.

```
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static string Import_TestFunc()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            // Find out how many files DSAMS processing requires.
            command.CommandText = @"EXEC get_parameter 'filecount' ";
            string cnt = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cnt))
            {
                return "'cnt' not found."; // error return code. can't find this parameter.
            }
           return cnt;
        }
    }
```

However, this does not work.  It constantly thinks the value for cnt is null (or empty) when it returns from get_parameter.

As requested, the code for get_parameter

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_parameter] 
(
    @SelectedParameterName nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);

    SET @result = (SELECT ParameterValue from Parameters WHERE ParameterName = @SelectedParameterName);

    RETURN isnull(@result,'');

END
```

---

I have tried the solution as per Mike Dinescu below, but it problem is that the call to ExecuteScalar() still returns a null. I did try to change to CommandType.Text and in that case I get the following interesting message:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Import_TestFunc": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'get_parameter' expects parameter '@SelectedParameterName', which was not supplied.
```

This is interesting, because I'm looking right at where it adds the parameter @SelectedParameterName.

```
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SelectedParameterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar )).Value = "filecount";
```

Comment: Are you perhaps comparing apples with oranges? Your SQL function is not doing exactly the same as your manual script. `EXEC get_parameter 'filecount'` is not the same as `SET … = dbo.get_parameter('filecount')`.

Comment: You said this a function but in your CLR you are calling like a procedure. Change your CLR code to "Select dbo.get_parameter('filecount')"

Comment: Show us the definition of `dbo.get_parameter`.  At least the header, if not the whole body.

Comment: I tried this. Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a user-defined function, or stored procedure from .NET, you should set the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure, and add the needed parameters to the command object before executing the command.

```
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.CommandText = @"dbo.get_parameter";

 // here you add the paramters needed for your procedure/function
 //   in your case it will be just one (make sure you add the correct name for you function)
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamter("SelectedParameterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));

 command.Prepare();

 command.Parameters[0].Value = "filecount";

 string cnt = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Doesn't recognize CommandType.StoredProcedure even though I have using System.Data.SqlClient, also doesn't recognize new SqlCommandParameter()

Comment: NVM. Adding using System.Data fixed both of those.

Comment: Interestingly, when I set CommandType.Text and set the CommandText to @"select parametervalue  from IF103_Parameters where ParameterName = 'dsams_filecount'" ... IOW, when I use a direct select instead of a stored procedure call, it works.